# for loop and animation, can't use variable since changing due to closure

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I have this code:

```
   var newTR = '<tr class=".small"></tr>';
   var i=300, v=0;

    for (var product in products){
        i=i+300;
        v++;

        var newTD+v =
            '<td>'+'img'+'</td>'+
                '<td>'+products[product].partNumber + ' ' + products[product].description+'</td>'+
                '<td class="productPrice">' + toDollars(products[product].price) + '</td>'+
                '<td class="productQty">'+products[product].qty+'</td>'+
                '<td>'+ products[product].price * products[product].qty+'</td>'+
                '<td><button class="removeProductClass">x</button></td>';

        $(newTR)
            .delay(i)
            .insertAfter(self.cartTableHeader)
            .switchClass( "small", "big", 500, "easeInOutQuad")
            .queue(function(){
                $(this).append(newTD)
                    .children()
                    .hide()
                    .fadeTo(1000, 1);
                    $(this).dequeue();
                })
            .queue(function(){
                self.calcSubTotal();
                $(this).dequeue();
                });


    }
}
```

The problem is that I end up with the same value for newTD variable 
since closure is using the last value that was set on newTD
since animation happens later, when for loop already completed..

How can one overcome this? :(

thanks for reading,

Sean.

Comment: You need to call a function with the CURRENT value of newTD and any other data you want to pass, and then call your delay with that info.

Comment: `var newTD+v = ` isn't valid syntax.

Comment: Actually I don't see any closure here? If you had used one in the right place, it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the code in question in a self executing function like so:

```
       (function(newTD){
          $(newTR)
            .delay(i)
            .insertAfter(self.cartTableHeader)
            .switchClass( "small", "big", 500, "easeInOutQuad")
            .queue(function(){
                $(this).append(newTD)
                    .children()
                    .hide()
                    .fadeTo(1000, 1);
                    $(this).dequeue();
                })
            .queue(function(){
                self.calcSubTotal();
                $(this).dequeue();
                });
       })(newTD);
```

Comment: Hi Bergi, yes there is Closure since the value of newTD is dropping down into all the queue functions exposing the last value set.